# Why we need to version of provider in terraform,

Tags: terraform

Why we need to provide version always in provider in terraform, is there any specific reason for it? please explain
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you need to provide a specific version is down to the provider. **The reason you would want to specify a version for a provider is to prevent pulling in backwards incompatible changes.**